# scheme equivalent to ruby debug 'p' statement

Tags: ruby, scheme, racket

I'm trying to debug some scheme code. It would be helpful if I could print the contents of a variable or binding out.

Is there an equivalent to the 'p' statement of Ruby in Scheme.

In particular, I'm using Racket.

Comment: Are you looking for `print`?  See: http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._print%29%29  and http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/read-write.html for more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no p equivalent, but it's fairly easy to roll your own.

```
#lang racket

(define-syntax-rule (p e)
  (let ([ans e])
    (printf "~a => ~a\n" (quote e) ans)
    ans))

(p (+ 1 2))
```

outputs

```
(+ 1 2) => 3
3
```

As a low-tech alternative, you may also be interested in the [C-c C-l keyboard shortcut in Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/Keyboard_Shortcuts.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can display the contents of a variable on the evaluation window using [`display`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._display%29%29), or if you want more control over the formatting of the output, [`printf`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._printf%29%29). But that's just equivalent to calling `puts` in Ruby - I can't think of a direct equivalent to `p` in Scheme, given that Ruby's `p` calls `inspect` on the object.

Comment: `write` is pretty similar, though, in that it outputs a `read`able version if possible.

Comment: The most important property of `p` is that it evaluates to its argument, which means that you can insert it anywhere into an expression without changing its result, whereas `print` and `puts` evaluate to `nil`. From the looks of it, `display` and the `printf` family don't do that.